# Load module into apache + mod-wsgi

Tags: python, apache, mod-wsgi

I am using Apache + mod-wsgi.

In my httpd.conf, I am having the following additional lines at the end of file.

```
LoadModule wsgi_module modules/mod_wsgi-win32-ap22py27-3.3.so
WSGIScriptAlias / "C:/Projects/Folder/web/"
<Directory "C:/Projects/Folder/web">
AllowOverride None
Options None
Order deny,allow
Allow from all
</Directory>
```

When I execute the following `index.py` scripts in Windows through http://localhost/script/index.py

```
def application(environ, start_response):
    status = '200 OK' 
    output = 'Hello World!'
    response_headers = [('Content-type', 'text/plain'),
                        ('Content-Length', str(len(output)))]
    start_response(status, response_headers)
    return [output]
```

Works pretty fine.

However, when I add `import utils` at the first line of `index.py`, I get

```
ImportError: No module named utils
```

`utils.py` is same directory as `index.py`

Is there any additional configuration I need to set?

I try suggestion given by @dan_waterworth

```
import sys, os
sys.path.append(os.path.dirname(__file__))
```

I get no more error by importing my own module. However, when I import module which is being installed through easy_install, error happens.

```
   File "C:/Projects/Folder/web/script\\connection.py", line 1, in <module>
     import psycopg2
   File "build\\bdist.win32\\egg\\psycopg2\\__init__.py", line 65, in <module>
     from psycopg2 import tz
 ImportError: cannot import name tz
```

`import psycopg2` executed no problem, if this script is being executed as standalone application.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I find that I have to add a few lines to append the python path. Something like:

```
import sys, os
sys.path.append(os.path.dirname(__file__))

import utils
```

for the second part, just add additional lines for your import directories. ie:

```
sys.path.append([enter path here])
```

to find your import directories, type into an interactive python prompt:

```
import sys
print sys.path
```

Comment: 11 seconds before, broader and a more generic solution :) +1

Comment: I get NameError: name 'os' is not defined

Comment: sorry, I forgot to add os to the import, try now

Comment: @ dan_waterworth, thanks. there is improvement. however, i get error while i try to import module which is being installed through easy_install. i update my question.

Answer (score 1):

The other answers focus on getting the script itself to mangle its own PYTHONPATH.  Another approach is to figure out the right Apache settings that will setup a workable path for Python and WSGI apps.

I have these in my conf file:

```
PassEnv PYTHONPATH
WSGIPythonHome  C:/Python/Python26
WSGIPythonPath  C:/Python/Python26;C:/myproject/PyLib
```

If you don't want to pass your environment's PYTHONPATH, I think you can use:

```
SetEnv PYTHONPATH C:/your/paths/go/here;C:/and/here
```

I suggest you give these a shot.

Answer (score 0):

`sys.path` and `sys.modules` to check whether the directory is actually added as a module directory. If not `sys.path.append` it.

Comment: It's not really necessary to check. Python will just use the first one that works, if there's duplicates it wastes a small fraction of a second at most and the code is easier to read.

Comment: I meant that for him to analyze the situation. Maybe the directory actually exists in the `sys.path` in the first place and the problem is not in the importing. Otherwise thanks.